# Find the number of reference links present on a webpage

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, nlp

I have following question to answer. I am following all these steps but getting the answer as 1568 or 1572. But apparently both these answers are incorrect. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong here.

---

Read the html content from the link 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)'. Store the content in the variable html_content.

Create a BeautifulSoup object with html_content and html.parser. Store the result in the variable soup.

Find the number of reference links present in the soup object. Store the result in the variable n_links.

Hint: Make use of the find_all method, and a tags.

Print n_links.

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Also, what is the expected answer number?

Comment: Repeatedly saying it is the wrong answer without telling us what the right answer is expected to be is frustrating. Is there a reason why you are not sharing that info with us?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a semantic thing going on here. Unsure as you don't specify the actual target number for the answer. If the links required are from the `references` section then you need to restrict to that section of html with parent class. I would use css selectors applied via `select` in that case. This gives `391`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

html_content = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#References').content
soup = bs(html_content, 'html.parser')
n_links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.reflist a')]
print(len(n_links))
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a different perspective. But this answer did not worked as well.

Comment: What is the expected number for the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib import request
import re

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)"
html_content = request.urlopen(url).read()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

n_links = []

for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
    n_links.append(link.get('href'))

print(n_links)
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation along with your code?